# Swapping maximum and minimum values in a list

Tags: python

Given a list (for instance, [1,1,2,1,2,2,3]) which is not sorted highest to lowest, and contains multiples of all numbers, I need to swap, in place, the maximums with the minimums, the second maxes with the second mins, etc. So, our example list would become [3,3,2,3,2,2,1].

Also, just to clarify, it's not just the max and min, but each layer of maxes and mins. So if the max was 4, 1's and 4's should switch as well as 2's and 3's.

I found this question on the topic: [How to swap maximums with the minimums? (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040018/how-to-swap-maximums-with-the-minimums-python?rq=1)

but the code examples given seemed verbose, and assumed that there were no duplicates in the list. Is there really no better way to do this? It seems like a simple enough thing.

Comment: Why is there a different amount of each integer in the input and output? It seems like it is merely `[4 - x for x in src]`, instead of preserving the actual values.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what ought to happen in the case of `[1, 1, 8, 9]` - should the result be `[9, 9, 8, 1]` or `[9, 9, 2, 1]`? I assumed the former in my answer, but some other answers are assuming the latter.

Comment: It's as you said. The 8 stays the same, since it is middle in terms of layers of max/min.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one way to do it, possible because Python is such an expressive language:

```
>>> a = [1,1,2,1,2,2,3]
>>> d = dict(zip(sorted(set(a)), sorted(set(a), reverse=True)))
>>> [d[x] for x in a]
[3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1]
```

Comment: How about extracting `sa = sorted(set(a))` and using `dict(zip(sa, reversed(sa)))`